# Access forms - edit record from query with join on linked table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, linked-tables

My setup is using Access 2000 with linked tables to an SQL 2008 server.

I have created a form that displays data from a single linked table that joins with 1 field from a view in the database (see SQL below). The relationship between the table and the view is a 1:1, why this should not cause a problem. However, I experience that I cannot update records in the recordset via the form. I get the error message "Recordset cannot be updated" when attempting to write in one of the fields.

According to http://rogersaccessblog.blogspot.dk/2009/11/this-recordset-is-not-updateable-why.html there is a lot of problems regarding this, but I would say I fulfill the rules for not having the recordset not being updateable.

I have seen it work with the same setup, so I am puzzled as to why it locks the recordset now.

This is my SQL query:

```
    SELECT dbo_Balance.*, 
[dbo_Amount_summary_all_specifications].[SUM_AMOUNT] AS Specification
    FROM dbo_Amount_summary_all_specifications 
RIGHT JOIN dbo_Balance ON 
([dbo_Amount_summary_all_specifications].[Version]=[dbo_Balance].[Version]) AND
([dbo_Amount_summary_all_specifications].[Year]=[dbo_Balance].[Year]) AND
([dbo_Amount_summary_all_specifications].[Period]=[dbo_Balance].[Period]) AND
([dbo_Amount_summary_all_specifications].[Kardex]=[dbo_Balance].[Kardex]) AND
([dbo_Amount_summary_all_specifications].[Account]=[dbo_Balance].[Account])

WHERE [dbo_balance].[Balance]<>0;
```

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE 2014-03-12**

My source for the data in my SQL database:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[VW_Overview_balance]
AS SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.Balance.ID, dbo.Balance.Year, dbo.Balance.Period,
dbo.Balance.Version, dbo.Balance.Kardex, dbo.Balance.Account, dbo.Balance.Kardex_name,
dbo.Balance.Kardex_code, dbo.Balance.Kardex_hierarki, dbo.Balance.Coop_franchise,
dbo.Balance.Chain, dbo.Balance.Chain_name, dbo.Balance.Responsible, 
dbo.Balance.Balance, dbo.Balance.Comment, dbo.Balance.Bank_account, 
dbo.Balance.Approver, dbo.Balance.Timestamp, dbo.VW_specifications_bank.SUM_AMOUNT_bank,
dbo.VW_specifications_system.SUM_AMOUNT_system,dbo.VW_specifications_erp.SUM_AMOUNT_erp, 
dbo.VW_specifications_user.SUM_AMOUNT_user, dbo.SUM_Total_Balance.Tot_Balance, - 
ISNULL(dbo.Balance.Bank_account, 0) - ISNULL(dbo.VW_specifications_erp.SUM_AMOUNT_erp, 0) 
+ ISNULL(dbo.VW_specifications_bank.SUM_AMOUNT_bank, 0) - 
ISNULL(dbo.VW_specifications_system.SUM_AMOUNT_system, 0) - 
ISNULL(dbo.VW_specifications_user.SUM_AMOUNT_user, 0) AS Specification, 
dbo.SUM_Total_Balance.Tot_Balance - ISNULL(dbo.Balance.Bank_account, 0) - 
ISNULL(dbo.VW_specifications_erp.SUM_AMOUNT_erp, 0)  +
ISNULL(dbo.VW_specifications_bank.SUM_AMOUNT_bank, 0) -
ISNULL(dbo.VW_specifications_system.SUM_AMOUNT_system, 0)  -
ISNULL(dbo.VW_specifications_user.SUM_AMOUNT_user, 0) AS Difference, dbo.Account.Account_name

FROM dbo.Balance LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Account ON 
dbo.Balance.Account = dbo.Account.Account_no LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SUM_Total_Balance 
ON dbo.Balance.ID = dbo.SUM_Total_Balance.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.VW_specifications_bank 
ON dbo.VW_specifications_bank.Balance_id = dbo.Balance.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.VW_specifications_erp 
ON dbo.VW_specifications_erp.Balance_id = dbo.Balance.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.VW_specifications_system 
ON dbo.VW_specifications_system.Balance_id = dbo.Balance.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.VW_specifications_user
ON dbo.VW_specifications_user.Balance_id = dbo.Balance.ID

WHERE     (dbo.Balance.Kardex_code <> 3) 
AND (dbo.Balance.Kardex_code <> 13) 
AND (dbo.SUM_Total_Balance.Tot_Balance <> 0) 
AND (dbo.Balance.Account IN
(SELECT Account_no FROM dbo.Account AS Account_1))
```

The query in the Access database has been reduced to:

```
SELECT dbo_VW_Overview_balance.Kardex, dbo_VW_Overview_balance.Account,
dbo_VW_Overview_balance.Kardex_name, dbo_VW_Overview_balance.Kardex_hierarki,
dbo_VW_Overview_balance.Coop_franchise, dbo_VW_Overview_balance.Chain_name,
dbo_VW_Overview_balance.Responsible, dbo_VW_Overview_balance.Comment,
dbo_VW_Overview_balance.Approver, dbo_VW_Overview_balance.Tot_Balance,
dbo_VW_Overview_balance.Specification, dbo_VW_Overview_balance.Difference,
dbo_VW_Overview_balance.Year, dbo_VW_Overview_balance.Period,
dbo_VW_Overview_balance.Version, dbo_VW_Overview_balance.Account_name

FROM dbo_VW_Overview_balance

ORDER BY dbo_VW_Overview_balance.Kardex, dbo_VW_Overview_balance.Account;
```

Comment: What is the `Recordset Type` on your form? Is it `Dynaset [Inconsistent Updates]`

Comment: It is `Dynaset`. I have tried with `Dynaset [Inconsistent Updates]` but that did not seem to work - at least not in the first test. I will test again in a minute, when I have new data to work with :-)

Comment: I have now tested with both `Dynaset` and Dynaset `[Inconsistent Updates]` and the results remain the same: Cannot update recordset :-(

Comment: Could you provide table layouts and sample data?

Comment: Since I originally posted this thread, I have made some alterations. Fundamentally, instead of using join and having calculated fields in my Access SQL query, I have made a series of views in the SQL database that performs this in order to having a simple query to display the data. This appeared to work for me as I was able to write to the fields in the form... at least for a while as the problem appears to having returned though I do not see what have changed.

Anyhow, this is the view that prepares the data in the database:

Comment: @Zaider: I have altered my original post to include the alterations I have made in order to show the source I am using (the view in the SQL database) and the query I use in the Access layer to display data in the Form. I hope this provides some help, but otherwise please let me know and I will provide all I can and am allowed to.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help from [support.microsoft.com/KB/304179](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/304179) I figured a solution: Though I had primary keys on the SQL database, I had not configured this in the linked table in Access as well. By updating the linked table and manually assigning the primary key, I can now update the recordset through both query and form!